# Is it possible to use wild cards in json validation or ignore some values in json in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

My `jmeter` application sends a request and expects the following `json` in the response.

```
{"external-profile":{"email":"myemail@gmail.com","firstname":"fn","lastname":"ln","portfolio":{"field1":[],"field2":[],"field3":[]}}}
```

`field1`, `field2` and `field3` could be empty arrays or might have some value. Is there a way to check that the message has `field1,2,3` but ignore the value?

I tried doing this but it doesn't work - `{"external-profile":{"email":"myemail@gmail.com","firstname":"fn","lastname":"ln","portfolio":{"field1":[\.*],"field2":[\.*],"field3":[\.*]}}}`. To be honest, I don't know if this is the right way to specify regular expressions in `jmeter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [JMeter 5.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter-5.2) you have [JSON JMESPath Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Assertion) which provides [`keys` function](https://jmespath.org/proposals/functions.html#keys), using it you can validate the attributes names, example configuration:

[image]

And textual representations for easier copying and pasting:

- JMESPath: `join(',',keys("external-profile".portfolio))`
- Expected value: `field1,field2,field3`

However it will fail if the order of "fields" will be different so you might want to go for [JSON Schema Validator](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema) instead, it can be used from [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion)

Comment: Thanks. The `json` I mentioned is incomplete. The actual structure is `{"result":"success","additional-info":"{\"external-profile\":{\"email\":\"myemail@gmail.com\",\"firstname\":\"fn\",\"lastname\":\"ln\",\"portfolio\":{\"field1\":[],\"field2\":["value1","value2"],\"field3\":[]}}}"}`. I modified your answer as follows `join(',',keys("additional-info.external-profile".portfolio))` but got error `message:Invalid argument type calling "keys": expected object but was null`

Comment: I also tried `join(',',keys("additional-info"."external-profile".portfolio))` but that also gives error `Assertion failure message:Invalid argument type calling "keys": expected object but was null`. The response contains `json` - `{"result":"success","additional-info":"{\"external-profile\":{\"email\":\"myemail@gmail.com\",\"firstname\":\"fn\",\"lastname\":\"ln\",\"portfolio\":{\"field1\":[],\"field2\":[{\"tag\":\"un2-new tag-empty\",\"count\":1},{\"tag\":\"un2-new tag2-empty\",\"count\":1}],\"field3\":[]}}}"}`

Comment: I think the problem might be that `additional-info` is a string and not a json object `"additional-info":"{...}"` instead of `"additional-info":{...}`. I need to find a way to convert it to `json` object before I can validate the paths. But I don't know if I can use something like `json.parse` to do this.

Comment: I got it working after I converted the string into json object. Your answer is correct w.r.t. the question I had originally created. More details here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65151285/jmes-path-assertion-failing-in-jmeter/65167630#65167630