# jmes path assertion failing in jmeter

Tags: jmeter-5.0, jmespath

In my `jmeter` test, the test receives the following `json` response.

`{"result":"success","additional-info":"{\"external-profile\":{\"email\":\"myemail@gmail.com\",\"firstname\":\"fn\",\"lastname\":\"ln\",\"portfolio\":{\"tags-of-interest\":[],\"question-created-tags\":[{\"tag\":\"un2-new tag-empty\",\"count\":1},{\"tag\":\"un2-new tag2-empty\",\"count\":1}],\"question-answered-tags\":[]}}}"}`

I want to check that the  message has path `additional-info.exernal-profile.portfolio` and that there are keys `tags-of-interest`, `question-created-tag`,`question-answered-tag`

I am using `json jmes path` but I am getting error `Assertion failure message:Invalid argument type calling "keys": expected object but was null`

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go for 2 [JSON JMESPath Extractors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor):

1. Extract the content of `additional-info` attribute into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from the response

   [image]
2. Extract the attributes from the `external-profile` attribute:

   [image]

You can see the extracted values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination:

[image]

---

Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting as:

- Groovy has [built-in JSON support](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- Groovy is more Java-compliant when it comes to modern language features support (lambdas, generics, etc.)
- Groovy has better performance
- Groovy provides [improvements on top of Java SDK](https://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html)

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `additional-info` was a `string` and not an object. I used `minimal-json-0.9.5` and `beanshell post processor` scripting to convert the strings into json objects.

Beanshell code

```
import com.eclipsesource.json.*;

//prev.setSuccessful(false);
try {
    String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); //response as string
    log.info("received json string: "+jsonString);
    
    JsonObject responseAsJsonObject = JsonObject.readFrom(jsonString); //convert response string as json
    log.info("converted to object: "+responseAsJsonObject);
    
    String additionalInfoString = responseAsJsonObject.get("additional-info").asString(); //get additional info string from json object
    log.info("additional info as string: "+additionalInfoString);
    
    JsonObject additionalInfoJsonObject = JsonObject.readFrom(additionalInfoString); //convert additional info string to json
    log.info("additional info as object: "+additionalInfoJsonObject);
    
    JsonObject externalProfileJsonObject = additionalInfoJsonObject.get("external-profile").asObject(); //get external profile object
    log.info("external profile as object: "+externalProfileJsonObject);
    
    JsonObject portfolioJsonObject = externalProfileJsonObject.get("portfolio").asObject(); //get portfolio object
    log.info("portfolio as object: "+portfolioJsonObject);
    
    JsonArray tagsOfInterest = portfolioJsonObject.get("tags-of-interest").asArray();
    log.info("tags of interest: "+tagsOfInterest);
    
    JsonArray tagsCreated = portfolioJsonObject.get("question-created-tags").asArray();
    log.info("tags created: "+tagsCreated);
    
    JsonArray tagsAnswered = portfolioJsonObject.get("question-answered-tags").asArray();
    log.info("tags tagsAnswered: "+tagsAnswered);
//  prev.setSuccessful(true);
} catch (Exception e){
    log.info("error in processing beanshell script: ", e);
    prev.setSuccessful(false);
}
```

[image]