# how to specify nested json path in jmespath and jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmespath

My `jmeter` test receives the following `json` response

```
{"result":"success","additional-info":"{"external-profile":{"email":"myemail@gmail.com","firstname":"fn","lastname":"ln","portfolio":{"tags-of-interest":[],"question-created-tags":[{"tag":"un2-new tag-empty","count":1},{"tag":"un2-new tag2-empty","count":1}],"question-answered-tags":[]}}}"}
```

I am trying to validate that a path exists. I am able to validate that the top level path exists but I can't validate that the nested path exsits.

Eg. validating `"additional-info"` works but `"additional-info"."external-profile"` doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

This works

[image]

This fails with error `JMESPATH "additional-info"."external-profile" expected to exist`

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is that the server is returning `additional-info" as string `"{...}"` and not as `json` `{}`. Is there something like `JSON.parse` function which I could use to convert string json into json object?

Comment: Answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65151285/jmes-path-assertion-failing-in-jmeter/65167630#65167630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go for 2 [JSON JMESPath Extractors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor):

1. Extract the content of `additional-info` attribute into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from the response

   [image]
2. Extract the attributes from the `external-profile` attribute:

   [image]

You can see the extracted values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) listener combination:

[image]